# Why is the target disabled in dot net shortcuts after setup?

Tags: .net, winforms, shortcut

go to any dotnet application shortcut **made by dotnet setup**  and click property, in the screen that's come up, why find target button is disabled?!

this just happened to the shortcut produced by dotnet Setup, why? and how to enable it?

Comment: So, as you can see from my answer, this is a better way. Use advertised shortcuts.

Comment: You'll have to use Orca MSI Editor, or use info in this link - http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/vs-net-setup/921/Set-DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS-property-in-VS-NET-setup-project

Comment: why just donnet setup project is doing like this, and the other not?!
install shield ... all don't do like this..
I don't want to use Orca, I'm reading the other link.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> This is a feature of Windows Installer
> and is called "[Advertised Shortcut](http://msipackagingforvista.com/what-is-an-advertised-shortcut.html)".
> This shortcut contains information
> about the product it is pointing to.
>
> You can turn this
> on/off in your setup, by setting the
> DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS property.

### Advertised Shortcut

> In the MSI world there are two types
> of shortcut - advertised and
> non-advertised.
>
> A non-advertised shortcut is a
> standard windows shortcut. If you
> right-click it you will see the target
> field points to the executable that
> will be launched. If, for whatever
> reason, this executable is missing the
> application will simply fail.
>
> An advertised shortcut is a
> technology specific to Windows
> Installer. If you right-click an
> advertised shortcut the target field
> will be greyed out. An advertised
> shortcut supports advertisement and
> repair.
>
> Repair means that if the executable to
> which the shortcut is pointing is not
> there then windows installer will
> repair the application and replace the
> missing file. In fact, it will also
> check other important files, flagged
> as key paths, and if any of those are
> missing it will replace them as well.
>
> Advertisement is a process in which
> the application appears to be
> installed the shortcuts are there but
> the application is not actually
> installed. The installation, the
> copying of files and registry entries,
> only takes place when the user first
> launches the application. An
> advertised install only puts down what
> we call the application interfaces. An
> application interface is any way to
> start the application. This could be a
> shortcut, file extension or COM
> interface.

### EDIT

To add the property, you can use [Orca MSI Editor](http://www.technipages.com/download-orca-msi-editor.html), or take a look at how to [Set DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS property in VS.NET setup project](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/vs-net-setup/921/Set-DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS-property-in-VS-NET-setup-project) article.

### EDIT 2

Some more interesting info over [here](http://blog.jtbworld.com/2007/11/enable-target-and-change-icon-of.html). You can directly run setup.exe with the parameters - `setup.exe DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1` or `msiexec.exe <path to msi-file> DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1`.

And, if you are using [Orca MSI Editor](http://www.technipages.com/download-orca-msi-editor.html), you can set the property by opening your msi file, and going to the `Property` page (on the left), and adding a new property by right-clicking "`Add Row`" menu option. Save the msi, and you are done.

Comment: where I can find DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS property?

Comment: Really annoying part of this is that if you have an auto updater that applies custom patches on a regular basis, Windows Installer will randomly revert them to their install state when you activate the shortcut.