# Shortcut created by a VB.Net WinForms ClickOnce installation does not have a target tab

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, installation, clickonce

I have taken over support for a VB.Net WinForms application. When this application is installed via a ClickOnce installation it generates a shortcut on the desktop. The annoying thing, though, is that if you do a right click and properties on the shortcut that was created, it is clear that it is not a regular shortcut as it does not have a target tab, so it is not obvious from the shortcut properties what this shortcut is referencing. So my questions relating to this are: what is the idea behind this kind of shortcut? Why is the the target for this type of shortcut hidden? (What are they even called? This is the first time I have ever seen a ClickOnce installation, so was somewhat surprised when I found that the properties tab was missing.) How do you find out what executable is being referenced by the shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClickOnce shortcuts - like [those created by .Net setup programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270779/why-is-the-target-disabled-in-dot-net-shortcuts-after-setup) - are '[advertised shortcuts'](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/advertised-shortcuts.html), where the operating system validates the program before running it - and, if necessary, runs a MSI Repair on it. There's no way to determine the target .exe from the shortcut.

Comment: Thanks, Stuart for the answer. I managed to find the executable referenced by the 'advertised shortcut' by looking through the folders in the default location for ClickOnce installations.

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut is an "Advertised shortcut" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270779/why-is-the-target-disabled-in-dot-net-shortcuts-after-setup).
In order to find out what executable is being referenced by the shortcut do the following:

1. Run the application using the shortcut
2. Open the **task manager**.
3. Right click the record of the process and select **Go To Process**
4. Right click the record of the process and select **Open File Location**

And walla...

Comment: This worked in Windows 7 for me, but not XP.  After looking at the path, I can see why they want to keep it hidden.